# Customization in Panel

Tags: panel, customization

When I minimize folders and mozilla, it is not visible in the panel. I do not where it is stored.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you have removed the Window List Applet:

- If the panel is still there, right click on it and select *Add to Panel*, then choose *Window List* and click *add*.
- If the panel is gone completely, click the upper one and select *New Panel* first.

The default widgets on the bottom panel are, in order: *Show Desktop, Window List, Workspace Switcher and Rubbish Bin*.

Comment: thanks for suggestions. but the panels disappeared when I tried the link- ttp://www.liberiangeek.net/2010/09/applications-disappeared-click-minimize-button-restore-gnome-panels-ubuntu-10-0410-10-maverick-meerkat/. then later I tried http://www.raasukutty.com/blog/open-source/ubuntu-panel-missing.html. NOW I HAVE 2 PANELS. AND i COULD NOT EXIT TERMINAL AS PER 2ND LINK. THOUGH I GOT PANELS, STILL MY PROBLEM IS NOT SOLVED

Comment: @nitzsi try running `rm -rf ~/.gconf/apps/panel` again and log out and back in, see what that does. Please add a screen shot of your desktop to your question, if this doesn't solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

**Step-1:**
Right Click on your panel and choose **Add to Panel...**

[image]

**Step-2:**
The following window will appear,scroll down and choose **Windows List** and click on **Add.**
[image]